# Etiquette on posting possible duplicate for a new user

Tags: support, reputation, answers, duplicate-questions

I still don't have enough reputation to comment on a question.

I have come across questions which are duplicates. What do I do?

1. Do I answer telling this is a possible duplicate, please look at this post?
2. Do I just leave it alone for more reputed users to comment on
3. If both are not right, is there a third option?

For now I am following option 2, till someone gives a proper answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. **No**, please do not do this! Your post will only get deleted as Not an Answer, creating more work for the community.
2. That's always an option, but if you want to help contribute to the site, you can...
3. [**Flag** the post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/flag-posts) as a duplicate:

   [image: flag as duplicate]

   Note that this does require 15 reputation, however, but that shouldn't be too hard to get.

Comment: Thanks for quick answer. I have 36 reputation. But the flag 'it is a duplicate' does not appear in the flags option. Do I flag it as other and then give link to duplicate?

Comment: @CRags That's odd — you should be able to see the "duplicate" option. Could you provide a link to the post in question?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/567872/installing-tgz-driver

Comment: May be some sites need more reputation to flag as duplicates?

Comment: Ah, yes, it's a strange quirk with the flag privilege. See the privilege page I linked: "these options will not appear in the flag menu until you have earned ... the amount required for commenting"

Comment: I guess I will leave it as such. Or is it ok to choose other and type possible dupicate and give link?