# Is rep required to flag posts?

Tags: support, reputation, flags, duplicate-questions

I want to know if on the Stack Exchange sites, is it **is required to have reputation and if yes how much to flag posts?** It seems to me that I cannot use some flagging options.

*Here is an example:*

I wanted to mark this question as duplicate but I have only these flagging options:

[image]

As usual, all new Stack Exchange users are limited to use all options and features on it, therefore I want to ask if this is, again, the reputation system?

Comment: You need 50 reputation for close to appear per http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts

Comment: You can't flag that question as duplicate because it is already on hold. Only questions not on hold for and reason can be flagged for closure for any reason.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Etiquette on posting possible duplicate for a new user](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/246456/etiquette-on-posting-possible-duplicate-for-a-new-user)

Comment: No I am asking generally!

Answer (score 4):

I was the commenter talking to you. Sorry for not getting back to you, but yes, you need 50 rep to use the other flag options, and 15 rep to get the options you do currently.

As said [here](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/flag-posts):

[image]

The reason for this is simply to prevent abuse. You can imagine people registering to SE sites and flagging random answers just for the fun of it, or to annoy people - if they invest some time in the site to get 50 rep, then it is much less likely that they will be tempted to abuse the SE features.

Remember - if you get 200 rep on any one site, you get 100 rep on all your other sites to get you past the restriction!